# Edit the source file of an alias with that alias in bash

Tags: bash, alias

I've set a custom bashrc (~/.local/share/mybashrc)

I want to set an alias to edit this file from this file.

```
#~/.local/share/mybashrc

alias edit-conf='nano $0'
```

But this goes to "nano /bin/bash"

Is there any way to set alias to edit the current file?

Comment: `alias edit-conf='nano ~/.local/share/mybashrc'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` and `realpath` (or `readlink`):

```bash
mypath="$(realpath -e "${BASH_SOURCE[@]}")"
alias editconf="nano '$mypath'"
```

Comment: `-n` is redundant cause a trailing newline will get stripped by command substitution `$()`

Comment: Why `readlink` instead of `realpath`? `readlink -e` will also resolve all symlinks in the path, which might not be what OP wants, though it wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @wjandrea Yes, I know it stripps away the newline, but it doesn't hurt to remove it either. Since it's going to be stripped away and there is an option to not output it at all we can just as well skip outputting it. When it comes to `readlink` vs. `realpath` I don't have a strong preference in this case. Do you think `realpath` will be the better option?

Comment: Yeah, `realpath` does the job well enough, no need to resolve symlinks too.

Comment: My bad, apparently `realpath` also resolves symlinks unless you disable it with `-s`.

Comment: And it seems like they're both not available on Mac :[ Although there do seem to be Homebrew packages.

Comment: @wjandrea Yeah, I noticed :-)  I can't think of a problem with resolving them in this case so I think that's fine. For MacOS I guess one would need coreutils or similar. I've never worked on a Mac.

Comment: I think `alias editconf="nano '$BASH_SOURCE'"` is okay. Thanks BTW...